# how can I assign public IP on network interface on AWS lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-lightsail

I am trying to build a mail server in AWS lightsail.
How can I configure the static public IP attached to network interface?. I am building a mailserver with bind dns. requirement should be static IP. Public IP is already connected to instance but not resolving on MX record.

Current Config
Public IP 3.1.X.X.38
private IP 172.X.X.139

```
hostname 

mail.flexfuelph.com

/etc/hosts

3.X.X.38 mail.flexfuelph.com mail
```

no configured static IP on network interface. this is running on AWS lightsail.

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: In Amazon EC2 (and therefore I presume Lightsail), the public IP is actually linked to the Internet Gateway, which does a Reverse NAT to send traffic to the **private IP address** of the instance. The EC2 instance itself never knows (and never _needs_ to know) its public IP address. This allows the public IP address to be changed without having to change anything on the instance itself.

Comment: Yes. I did nothing on configuring the network interface. but it seems I have to define the public ip. Im getting a dns error on installation setup using bind dns.MX record shown (public ip ) interfacce is Private IP